# How do I set the publisher when generating a code signing certificate through Microsoft Certificate Services 2003

Tags: .net, clickonce

I am attempting to sign a ClickOnce manifest using a certificate generated from Certificate Services 2003 (by going to http://cert-server/certsrv, and requesting a code-signing cert from the browser).  When I install the application through ClickOnce, the Publisher of the application shows up as my personal name, rather than the name of the company.

For obvious reasons, I would prefer to have a cert issued that is not tied to a specific user, but the corporation.  How can I do this through Certificate Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to log into your Certificate Authority and use the [Certificate Manager Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0.aspx) to create a certificate with the desired name. You will first have to create the certificate by using the /add option.  At this point, it will only exist in the CA's certificate store.  Then, use the /put option so that it will output a X.509 certificate file. You can then take that file and install it on the developer machines (simply by double-clicking the file). The certificate will then exist in the Certificate Store, and thus will be available when you select the certificate you wish to sign with.

Visual Studio will also let you reference the certificate file directly, but leaving your certificate out in plain sight for anyone to use really undermines the "security" aspect of your certificate infrastructure.  It seems more convenient but has obvious consequences.

On a side note, at my company we actually *like* the fact that the primary developer's name appears on the certificate.  It conveys accountability and ownership.

Comment: Thanks, I will have our network admin try this on Monday.

The problem with using the primary developer's name on the certificate is that ClickOnce will treat the application as a different application if it is signed by a different cert.

If the developer leaves, using a new cert causes issues with the application being installed twice.

Comment: That is a known issue with Visual Studio 2005 and has been corrected in Visual Studio 2008. Both Wikipedia and I vouch for this. Upgrade already! :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce#Signatures

Comment: Is that corrected with Visual Studio 2008, or the .NET 3.5 framework?  We are using VS 2008 with .NET 2.0 and it appeared to be creating 2 separate applications when using two different certs.

Unfortunately we can't yet upgrade from .NET 2.0 due to some win2k machines that we still have to support.

Comment: It's corrected with VS2008.  If they have a version of the program that was installed by VS2005, they will have to uninstall/reinstall the program even if you moved to VS2008.  A clean install with VS2008 will not have the duplicate application problem.

Comment: Ok, that explains it then.  I had an old ClickOnce deploy installed from when I was testing ClickOnce with VisualStudio 2005.  Thanks for all your help.